# How to Combine Multiple Tableau Columns

Tags: sql, tableau-api

Let's say I have two columns in the data called 
        Functionality_First_Question and Functionality_Second_Question

Both columns have similar values 
        "approve", "functionality unclear", "functionality broken", NULL, etc.

Each row corresponds with a single, distinct review ID.

I thought about using Tableau combined fields to aggregate the data but will it end up turning into "functionality unclear, functionality broken".

I instead want just a distinct count of how many review IDs are associated with each answer to each question.

Let me know if this is unclear!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data source, you can pivot the data in the data source tab:

- highlight your First_Question, Second_Question, Nth_Question columns
- right click
- Pivot data

Now you have several records for each item (one record for each question) and you will be able to group all items by answer.

If this is not possible with your data source, one crude workaround would be:

- Create a parameter `Answer_param` with the different possible answers
- Create a calculated field that has a formula like

  `CONTAINS([First_Question], Answer_param) OR CONTAINS([Second_Question], Answer_param) OR ..`

This will create a field that is True, if one of the answers contains the selected answer from your parameter.